# Rest Assure : how to take the response header for the below mentioned scenario

Tags: httpclient, rest-assured

localhost:8188/wh/authorizewithdev?successUrl=http://localhost:8188/wh/noop

I have the URL as above.
When I hit the URL manually, it redirects to localhost:8188/wh/noop

If we see the Network by pressing F12, we can see two API hits.
One is localhost:8188/wh/authorizewithdev?successUrl=http://localhost:8188/wh/noop
with status code 303, in that we can see the response headers and it has the cookie_ticket with some value. ( Ultimate goal is that I need this cookie_ticket so that I can perform other actions with the cookie_ticket)

Second one is localhost:8188/wh/noop with status code 200 and in this if we see the response headers and request header. But in this hit the cookie_ticket will be passed as a request header. Cookie_ticket will not be present in the response header.

So when I hit the post(localhost:8188/wh/authorizewithdev?successUrl=http://localhost:8188/wh/noop) and tried to get the header I am able to get the response headers of the second one. But the cookie_ticket is not present.So is there any option to get the response headers of the first API hit or is there any option to get the request headers of the second API.
Please share your thoughts

Comment: I got it... by using given().redirects().follow(false).when(). ..

Comment: You should probably add this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I got it by using

```
given().redirects().follow(false).when()
```